# How can I solve TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' in list.sort() function?

Tags: python, sorting, typeerror

I'm using `pychem` library to calculate some chemical features.
But when I tried to use the module `basak`, I got "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" :(

I think the `sort()` function is suspicious for this error but I have no idea with handling this.
The part of the code including `sort()` function is given below:

```
from rdkit import Chem
import numpy
import copy

NumPath = 1
Hmol=Chem.AddHs(mol)
nAtoms=Hmol.GetNumAtoms()
TotalPath=Chem.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(Hmol,NumPath,useBonds=0,useHs=1)
if len(TotalPath)==0:
    BasakIC=0.0
else:
    IC={}
    for i in range(nAtoms):
        temp=[]
        at=Hmol.GetAtomWithIdx(i)
        temp.append(at.GetAtomicNum())
        for index in TotalPath:
            if i==index[0]:
                temp.append([Hmol.GetAtomWithIdx(kk).GetAtomicNum() for kk in index[1:]])
            if i==index[-1]:
                cds=list(index)
                cds.reverse()
                temp.append([Hmol.GetAtomWithIdx(kk).GetAtomicNum() for kk in cds[1:]])
        #print temp

        IC[str(i)]=temp
    cds=[]
    for value in IC.values():
        value.sort()
        cds.append(value)
    kkk=range(len(cds))
    aaa=copy.deepcopy(kkk)
    res=[]
    for i in aaa:
        if i in kkk:
            jishu=0
            kong=[]
            temp1=cds[i]
            for j in aaa:
                if cds[j]==temp1:
                    jishu=jishu+1
                    kong.append(j)
            for ks in kong:
                kkk.remove(ks)
            res.append(jishu)    

    #print res
    BasakIC=_CalculateEntropy(numpy.array(res,numpy.float)/sum(res))
```

Thank you in advance :)

+) The complete error message is this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-14f7f840abd4> in <module>
     24     cds=[]
     25     for value in IC.values():
---> 26         value.sort()
     27         cds.append(value)
     28     kkk=range(len(cds))

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: I added the message in the text!

Comment: looks like your `value` variable has `list` and `int` elements so you can not sort them

Comment: You cannot compare a sequence against an integer (Line 26). Btw, if IC itself is a list, then why do you need to traverse into the value and then sort? You can directly sort IC with IC.sort(). Isn't it ?

Comment: It's solved! 
Changing `temp.append()` to `temp.extend()` worked to solve this problem.

Thank you for you guys' help :)